# How to set jquery-bootgrid to manage navigation when data is loaded from AJAX?

Tags: jquery

When enabling server-side population, is there a way to load all data and let bootgrid manage the header and footer navigation?

Ex.
Option
data-ajax="true" data-url="../../data.json"

it is implicit that my service needs to manage the navigation by returning the current, rowCount, and total.

I need to load all available data and let bootgrid set and control the navigation headers.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or more information. Why you just don't init the plugin and trigger the needed event?

Comment: An example is here : http://jsfiddle.net/ZM8LW/9/ but for this to work we need a browser plugin Allow-Control-Allow-Origin from chrome. This is so we can read the json file that would result from a full load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. 
We just need to preload the data from the server and then append it to the empty table.

```
 $.ajax({url:"http://tainos.ca/data.json",success:function(result){
    $("#main-table").bootgrid().bootgrid("append", result.rows);
  }});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hevodev/ots9krjz/

Answer (score 0):

I never used this bootgrid by myself but I think you need rowCount to be -1...

See: http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#general

```
$("#main-table").bootgrid({
    rowCount: -1
});
```

Comment: This won't achieve what is asked by the OP. Even configuring bootgrid to load all rows in the same page like this, if someone sort or search, bootgrid will call API do get all data again. Moreover, OP still wants navigation/pages in the table, and not all data in one single row.